# How to create search box that extend itself when displaying filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a search box that extends itself downward when user input something

Here is an example

[image]

Right now I set up the html such that it displays all the possible values at the bottom of the search box

```
  Search: <input ng-model="query">
  <ul class="my_possible_values">
    <li ng-repeat="possible_value in my_possible_values | filter:query">
      {{possible_value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

However the listed element pushes down other div element below the search box instead of overlaying it.

Comment: Why not use `type-a-head` or `autocomplete` directives? E.g. since you are using twitter-bootstrap and angularjs try angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: you will love this: http://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingSearch

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `position: absolute` style on your `.my_possible_values` class -- that is how I've made/styled my search box dropdowns in the past. This will take the dropdown content out of the normal flow of the DOM, thus preventing it from pushing down the other divs on the page.

You can read more about CSS positions on this page :)
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Additionally, you'll probably want to add `overflow-y: scroll` and a `max-height` style to your `.my_possible_values` menu as well so that it does not overflow the bottom of the page if you have a lot of dropdown options.

I'd say those are the most important CSS rules for creating a good dropdown list. Good luck!